# Should I have the return line replaced when installing a new heat pump?

Tags: hvac

I have a 2000 sqft. house and need to replace a 4-ton R-22 system that uses a 1-1/8" return and has a short line run with the condenser 8 feet lower than the evaporator.

I have received quotes that recommend replacing with another 4-ton R-410a system, but the quotes differ on whether to reuse the existing 1-1/8" return line or install a new 7/8" line. The manufacturer install guide says that the system is rated for a 7/8" return line and does not mention 1-1/8".

Will a 4-ton unit still be enough with a smaller return line? Will using the existing bigger line cause problems since it's not rated for it?

Comment: How much labor does the changing of the line add. Have they explained how they will purge the old line. 410 systems need stronger joints. brazing is preferred method. Old soldered joints may well leak with the much greater pressure and smaller molecules of a 410 system. I would insist it be changed.

Comment: I have had two 5 ton AC units replaced in 20 years and the refrigerant lines were not replaced, they work fine.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I ended up having the line replaced with new 7/8", as the added expense was marginal.  Performance has been acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size really would not be a problem, the 410 is a higher pressure system and that allows for smaller tubing but will take more refrigerant (not much).

I am not a fan of reusing parts, yes they can be cleaned but I have had friends come to me after a new retrofit failed in less than 2 years.  The cause of the failure new Poe oil mixed with mineral oil that was not cleaned completely. This has happened 2x that I know of , is the evaporator rated for the 410a pressures?

I would make sure they will warranty all work like I said the size won’t be a problem but will they use that to get out of a warranty claim?  Both my friends had systems retrofitted by hvac companies they only knew they cooled the house. Both companies used the existing equipment as the reason for failure , it won’t affect the system but if you re use anything make sure the system is covered by the warranty as installed.

To cover the system they may want to replace the line, don’t let that be a reason for them to deny warranty coverage but it would not be a problem in theory.